# PHP syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: nginx, laravel, php

I never had this happen before, but here we go:

[image]

Any ideas?

- Running php-fpm 5.3
- Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin)

It looks as if the comment is NOT working...

Comment: Short array syntax was introduced in PHP 5.4... use `array('as' => 'default.index', ...)`

Comment: Are you sure you opened your comments properly looking at the syntax highlight it looks like you are missing the opening /*

Comment: @kaning that's a screenshot of Laravel's error page (using Symfony component), not a code editor.

Comment: You can avoid sudden errors like this by making sure your test-environment has the same installation and configuration as the production-environment! Same error confronted me when I was deploying my application on the server: local php version was 5.5 and on prod-server 5.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `[]` as arrays like that only works with PHP 5.4 and up.

> See [PHP: Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

You'll have to use old array syntax for PHP 5.3.

This will work:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'default.index', 'uses' => 'DefaultController@index'));
```